# What is band stacking?

Tags: transceiver, jargon, equipment-operation

What is a band stacking register and/or band stacking buttons on a transceiver?  And why would this be useful to an amateur radio operator?

Is using "band stacking" a current operating technique, or are there more modern operating methods? (such as wide panadapters with spotting network annotations, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's just a fancy memory feature to let you quickly switch to a preset frequency and operating mode. https://www.k0pir.us/icom-band-stacking-register-and-memo-pad/ and https://www.manualslib.com/manual/965457/Icom-Ic-7600.html?page=38 .  As the second URL mentions, it would be useful if you operate multiple modes in one band, so you can quickly switch from (for example) 40m RTTY to 40m CW to 40m SSB by just pushing one button.